# I need to flatten a JSON web response with nested arrays [[ ]] into a DataFrame

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert an `http JSON` response into a `DataFrame`, then out to `CSV` file.

I'm struggling with the `JSON into DF`.

http line:
http://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZEUR&interval=1440

JSON response (part of - 720 records in arrays):
[formatted using a JSON site does not post here apparently]

```
{
        "error": [],
    "result": {
             "XXBTZEUR": [
            [1486252800, "959.7", "959.7", "935.0", "943.6", "945.6", "4423.72544809", 5961],
            [1486339200, "943.8", "959.7", "940.0", "952.9", "953.5", "4464.48492401", 7678],
            [1486425600, "953.6", "990.0", "952.7", "988.5", "977.3", "8123.94462701", 10964],
            [1486512000, "988.4", "1000.1", "963.3", "987.5", "983.7", "10989.31074845", 16741],
            [1486598400, "987.4", "1007.4", "847.9", "926.4", "934.5", "22530.11626076", 52668],
            [1486684800, "926.4", "949.0", "886.0", "939.7", "916.7", "11173.53504917", 12588],
        ],
        "last": 1548288000
    }
}
```

I get

```
KeyError: 'XXBTZEUR'
```

on the `json_normalize` line. Seems to indicate to me that `json_normalize` is trying to build the `DF` from the "XXBTZEUR" level, not lower down at the record level. How do I get `json_normalize` to read the records instead. ie How do I get it to reference deep enough?

I have read several other posts on this site without understanding what I'm doing wrong.

One post mentions that `json.loads()` must be used. Is `json_string.json()` also loading the JSON object or do I need the `json.loads()` instead?

Also tried variations of `json_normalize`:

```
BTCEUR_Daily_Table = json_normalize(json_data[[]])
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Can normalize not load an array into a DF line?

code so far:

```
BTCEUR_Daily_URL = 'http://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZEUR&interval=1440'

json_string = requests.get(BTCEUR_Daily_URL)

json_data = json_string.json()

BTCEUR_Daily_Table = json_normalize(json_data, record_path=["XXBTZEUR"])
```

What I need in result:

In my DF, I just want the arrayed records shown in the "body" of the JSON structure.  None of the header & footer are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was:

BTCEUR_Daily_Table = json_normalize(data=json_data, record_path=[['result','XXBTZEUR']])

The 2nd parameter specifies the full "path" to the parent label of the records.
Apparently double brackets are needed to specify a full path, otherwise the 2 labels are  taken to mean 2 top level names.

Without another post here, I would never have found the solution.